# Alternatives to universe levels

Tags: type-theory, dependent-type

All of the type theory based proof assistants that I have seen have an infinite hierarchy of type universes to avoid the type of types being a term of itself. Are there alternative systems which could be implemented in a proof assistant, to solve the same problem, which don't involve universe levels?

Comment: You can restrict yourself to just one level, and that technically gets rid of the levels.

Comment: I believe type-in-type with only linear uses of variables is consistent. Very restrictive though.

Comment: Universe levels are often explained in terms of natural numbers. You have universe 0, universe 1 and so on. But really you don't need all that. All you need is universe a is less than universe b is less universe c. It's a little like New Foundations and stratification and it's kind of like some sorts of universe polymorphism.

Comment: Higher order logic, used in HOL Light, HOL4, and Isabelle/HOL, is a simple type theory with *no universes*.  Types and objects are different sorts, so you can quantify over objects in a type, but not over types themselves.  However, HOL implementations usually come with type polymorphism and types can also depend on other types (just not on elements of a type).

Comment: Yes, but not the common kind of type theory. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2151015/21820).