# Feferman's universes for proof assistants?

Tags: foundations, universe

I asked this question [on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/437462/) a few months ago, but received no answers.

There are some mathematicians who are [comfortable with ZFC but uneasy with large cardinals](https://mathoverflow.net/a/382670). For them, it may be unsettling that Mizar assumes infinitely many inaccessibles, and that Lean's dependent type theory makes a similar tacit assumption. Basically, this is because they appeal to Grothendieck universes.

Now, there is an alternative: Feferman's universes.  (For a brief explanation of Feferman's universes, see pages 24–25 of Mike Shulman's paper, [Set theory for category theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1279).)  Feferman's universes achieve most of what a "practicing mathematician" wants from Grothendieck's universes, but has the advantage of being conservative over ZFC. So here's my question:

> Suppose we wanted a proof assistant to avoid going beyond the consistency strength of ZFC, while retaining essentially all the functionality of something like Mizar or Lean. Could this be done using the Feferman-universe idea? How difficult would this be to implement and what would be the tradeoffs?

I see that there is a somewhat related question here on the Proof Assistants Stack Exchange, [Alternatives to universe levels](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/q/1610), but as of this writing, that question has no answers either.

Comment: I don’t know about Fereman’s universes, but you might want to look into the consistency strength of Isabelle/ZF and Metamath/set.mm (although I think the later uses universes). Also, if you just want a foundations commonly used in proof assistants but not stonger than ZFC, then IIRC Isabelle/HOL and HOL-Light both have a lower consistency strength than ZFC, but are very capable and practical theorem provers.

Comment: Can you explain the motivation for your question? What would be gained from having such a proof assistant?

Comment: @AndrejBauer I'm looking ahead to a future in which I hope more "working mathematicians" will use proof assistants, either directly (by coding up their own results) or indirectly (trusting proof assistants to vouchsafe the correctness of mathematical arguments). My anecdotal impression is that the use of universes, in one form or another, is becoming increasingly common in areas such as homotopy theory, algebraic geometry, and related areas. If and when these arguments are formalized, what will the implementation look like?

Comment: Feferman's trick won't work because the Feferman universe $V_\theta$ doesn't know that it's a model of ZFC. In fact, Feferman's compactness argument gives a non-standard model where $V \models \lnot(V_\theta \models \text{ZFC})$.

Comment: (continued) I'm guessing that, as things stand now, the formalizations will go beyond ZFC, because that is the most straightforward way to proceed. But the drawback is that some mathematicians will be unhappy with proofs that go beyond ZFC. I'm wondering if Feferman universes will allow informal arguments that use universes to be formalized more easily in a way that stays inside ZFC.

Comment: Ok, so you're not really looking for an explanation on how to implement things, correct? I mean, one can implement just about anything, and in the case at hand I'd take Isabelle/ZF and find a way of slapping Feferman's axiom on it. I am reading your question more generally as "what about universes?" and in particular "what if someone's worried about them". Is that a fair description?

Comment: @AndrejBauer Sort of. I want to know, from the perspective of a working mathematician who is not an expert in proof assistants but is willing to make some effort to learn them, whether the learning curve for formalizing universe-based proofs would be a lot steeper if accompanied by a demand to stay within ZFC. To put it another way, if I have a universe-based proof and I ask an expert for help formalizing it, and the expert says, "Just do this," will the expert's advice be significantly harder to obey if I add, "By the way, I don't want to exceed the consistency strength of ZF"?

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais What I have in mind is, suppose that a mathematician has already invested the time and effort to rework their proof to use Feferman universes, in a way that does not go beyond ZFC. Will it now be (relatively) straightforward for them to formalize their argument? That is, is it (relatively) easy to provide "support" for Feferman universes in this sense?

Comment: Here's another way to frame my concern. I can imagine that a library of "standard" results about universes might be built up over time, to ease the job of future mathematicians who want to formalize results that use universes. I can also imagine that such a library might freely go beyond ZFC because the people building the library see no reason not to. If someone then comes along and wants to use universes while staying within ZFC, are they stuck? You might object that I'm crossing bridges before I get to them. But if we want wider adoption of proof assistants then we have to think ahead.

Comment: If you have not yet tried formalizing mathematics? I can recommend do it. You will learn more than asking questions from the perspective of a working mathematician who is not an expert in proof assistants.

Comment: @AndrejBauer You are absolutely correct. It's certainly on my todo list. But I'm asking this question not just to learn something for myself. I'm alerting the experts to the sorts of things that people in my shoes are thinking. I don't know if you care about getting more people interested in formal proofs, but if you are, I would think it would be helpful for you to know what is in the minds of those who have not yet "drunk the Kool-Aid". For example, perhaps those in the proof assistant community don't fully appreciate how many working mathematicians care about consistency strength.

Comment: I can't help but to read "working mathematician" in your comments as "working logician" :-) Anyhow, I think I understand where you're coming from, so I can attempt an answer.

Comment: @AndrejBauer No, that's precisely the point. You might think that only working logicians would care about consistency strength, but the point is that when it comes to universes, working mathematicians are starting to care more, because of things like infinity-toposes and such. If you haven't already done so, I suggest clicking through my "comfortable with ZFC" link and reading Peter Scholze's answer in full, even though it's long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concrete suggestion you make, namely to use ZFC/S, is quite difficult to appraise. The only way to answer it is to actually try formalizing mathematics in it. One possibility is for you (or your students) to do it. Perhaps the fastest way to achieve something is to take Isabelle/ZF and modify it to support ZFC/S. Good luck!

However, I think the question should be read in a wider sense: what should be used by people who want to stay low on consistency strength? I am aware of two possibilities:

- In [Isabelle](https://isabelle.in.tum.de) land:

  - [Isabelle FOL and ZF](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/logics-ZF.pdf) ought to have the power of ZF, precisely.
  - [Isabelle/HOL](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/library/HOL/) has a huge library of formalized proofs based on classical higher-order logic. The consistency strength of HOL is quite low, and certainly below ZFC ($V_{\omega + \omega}$ models it).
- You can use [Metamath](https://us.metamath.org), see the [Metamath Proof Explorer](https://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/mmset.html) which contains over 23000 proofs based on ZFC.

There is a second sense to the question: must we reach for high consistency strength in order to use universes in practice?

I suspect, but cannot confirm, that in practice most uses of universes are "administrative" in the sense that they just serve as an organizing mechanism (a bit like having second-order logic without comprehension, or classes over ZFC), and not to boost the deductive power of the proof assistant. This leads to the question: are there formulations of type theory with universes which are "tame"?

Comment: I think Metamath (the set.mm library) uses universes, at least according to Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski-Grothendieck_set_theory

Comment: They do introduce the [Tarski-Grothendieck axiom](https://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/mmtheorems100.html#mm9903s), but I am not sure whether it gets used anywhere. For instance, the [category of categories](https://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/mmtheorems171.html#mm17064s) is parametrized by a universe, so it does not rely on there being any universes.

Comment: [Here](https://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/ax-groth.html) is where it is introduced.  I don’t know if it is used much.  It is easy check check for each theorem which axioms are used.

Comment: Actually, I just clicked through all the downstream dependencies, and there are only a handful of logical theorems.  So maybe the library is basically only ZFC?

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Regarding the "administrative" use of universes, that is precisely the issue that prompted this question. If you have not already done so, I recommend reading [Peter Scholze's answer to an MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/382670?_gl=1*13lb0hf*_ga*MTQ2MTY2NzY5MC4xNjY2ODc2MzA2*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY4Nzk5NzM2Ny4yMjUuMS4xNjg3OTk3MzcxLjAuMC4w), which I linked to in my question. It is long but it explains why he thinks that Feferman universes are more suitable than Grothendieck universes if one is concerned about consistency strength.

Comment: I sense a meta-theorem lurking in there somewhere. Isn't it the case that second-order arithmetic without comprehension is conservative over first-order arithmetic (I am probably misremebering)? I would imagine there has to be a way to formulate universes in type theory so that they are harmless but still useful.

Comment: One test-case to keep an eye on: without universes one cannot show in MLTT (without large eliminators) that $0 \neq 1$. So at least for type theories without large eliminators, administrative universes should not enable proving $0 \neq 1$.